# JOOQ IllegalArgumentException: Field () is not contained in Row

Tags: jooq

I am really confused by this and am not able to reason with the error at all.

```
Integer id = 5;
        if (id != null)
        {
            final var configurationResult = context.select(Configuration.CONFIGURATION)
                    .from(Configuration.CONFIGURATION)
                    .where(Configuration.CONFIGURATION.DEVICE_ID.eq(id))
                    .fetch();

            configurationResult.forEach(configuration -> {
                final var minTemp = configuration.getValue(Configuration.CONFIGURATION.MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD);
               System.out.println("MinimumTemp is: " + minTemp);
            });
        }
```

the exception is the most confusing:

```
Exception in thread "" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field ("public"."configuration"."minimum_temperature_threshold") is not contained in Row (row (
  "public"."configuration"."configuration_id",
  "public"."configuration"."minimum_temperature_threshold",
  "public"."configuration"."maximum_temperature_threshold",
  "public"."configuration"."ideal_temperature",
  "public"."configuration"."minimum_ph_threshold",
  "public"."configuration"."maximum_ph_threshold",
  "public"."configuration"."ideal_ph",
  "public"."configuration"."light_on_time",
  "public"."configuration"."light_off_time",
  "public"."configuration"."update_time",
  "public"."configuration"."device_id"
))
```

If I print the contents of the result I get the following

```
|configuration                                     |
|(6, 22, 28, 24, 7, 9, 8, 2023-05-15T18:00, 2023...|
```

So the data is there.

Can someone help me understand what is happening and help direct me in the right direction?

Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the table reference to your `select()` clause, then you're projecting a nested record. See the manual sections about:

- [`SelectField`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-clause/select-clause-selectfield/)
- [Nested records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/)
- [#4727](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4727) (the feature introduced in jOOQ 3.17)

This works just like in native PostgreSQL and offers powerful ways of nesting multiple [`TableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/TableRecord.html) types.

If you require only a single column (`CONFIGURATION.MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD`), then it should be sufficient to project only that.

I agree that the error message is confusing here. `Row (row (` is a (very) subtle hint at the problem, which isn't at all obvious. I've created an issue to address the error message: [#15085](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15085)

Comment: so If I do something like this:  final var configurationResult = context. Select(CONFIGURATION.MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD)
                    .from(Configuration.CONFIGURATION)
                    .where(Configuration.CONFIGURATION.DEVICE_ID.eq(id))
                    .fetch();
this would have worked?

Comment: @DamienCooke: Yes

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in this line:

```
final var configurationResult = context.select()
                    .from(Configuration.CONFIGURATION)
                    .where(Configuration.CONFIGURATION.DEVICE_ID.eq(id))
                    .fetch();
```

The select() method needed to be empty as I was selecting all the fields of the table.